# Does the server call "isset" all the time?

Tags: php

I've got some code which looks like this:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['surname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in...
```

in a file called register.inc.php. The only references to this file are

```
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
```

in the opening lines of a couple of other files.

What is puzzling is just how the php condition gets called. Is it called continuously, so that as soon as the variables have been set, it triggers? Or is it called when the page that includes it is loaded? Whatever, it doesn't seem to be called like a normal function. It all seems a bit mysterious and unexplained. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language. A value either exists or does not when running the script. Which means isset is called once per execution, or in a web server context, once per request including that PHP code.

Comment: I feel like we're missing part of the story here: what behaviour are you selling that makes you think that "it doesn't seem to be called like a normal function"?

Comment: @NoahBoegli Whether PHP is interpreted or compiled (which is actually debatable) doesn't have much to do with it: the function runs each time that part of the program is reached, just like any other line of code, and just as it would be if it was fully compiled.

Answer (score 2):

It is only called whenever it is called. If it's at the beginning of the file, then yes, it'll be called at the location where the file is included (at the location of the `include_once` call, in that case). It only performs the check once, returning true if, at the time it is called, all the variables exist (are set), false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you further learning PHP.

```
a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL, 'pie' => array('a' => 'apple'));

var_dump(isset($a['test']));            // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['foo']));             // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['hello']));           // FALSE
```

The above exactly explains how the isset() function can be used. If you are unsure how a PHP function works or looking for a new one, try to search the function on [https://www.php.net/][1] if you type your function here you'll be directed to the corresponding page.